# Required a Javascript program to find the first non-repeating element in given array of integer

Tags: javascript

Hi i need a javascript program which finds the element in the given array of integers which is placed in the array right before the first repeating element.

In this way, for the following example input:

```
-1 2 5 6 2 9 -1 6 5 6 -1 3
```

The output should come as `9`

In the same way when input is :- `4 2 6 2 5 4`

output has to be 6

Comment: `java !== javascript`

Comment: please add what you have tried.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code-writing service.  If it were, I'd be unemployed.

Answer (score -3):

You can use `array.prototype.find`, `array.prototype.indexOf` and `array.prototype.lastIndexOf`:

```js
var arr = [-1, 2, 5, 6, 2, 9, -1, 6, 5, 6, -1, 3];
var res = arr.find(e => arr.indexOf(e) === arr.lastIndexOf(e));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Is this Java or Javascript? Should you not wait for OP to clarify?

Comment: I don't think this can help the OP (obviously, copy-and-paste code won't help you be better at programming) or others (there is already a dupe).

Comment: [Related meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202895/should-we-downvote-answers-to-obvious-duplicate-questions).